# Putting some tables side by side

Tags: tables, subfloats, labels

I produced five Tables side by side, however, referring to them in the text, the labels did not work well. For example, writing 
`Table \ref{T2} \eqref{T2a}` resulted in 
`Table 1 (0a)` rather than `Table 1 (A)`. 
Similar errors took place in the case of other tables, i.e. writing `Tables \ref{T2} \eqref{T2b}, \eqref{T2c}, \eqref{T2d} and \eqref{T2e}` resuted in `Tables 1 (0b), (0c), (0d) and (0e)` rather than `Tables 1 (B), (C), (D) and (E)`. The following is my produced tables. How can I correct this error?

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{xy}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{qsymbols}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{plain}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\oddsidemargin=.25cm \evensidemargin=.25cm \textwidth=15cm
\topmargin=0cm \textheight=21cm
%\textwidth= \textheight=


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
%\centering
\scalebox{0.8}{
\subfloat[]{
\label{T2a}  
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
     $\alpha(E)$ & $H(n_0, r_0)$ \\
\hline
   $0.0046$ & $221.4469$ \\ 
   $0.0242$ & $234.2140$ \\
   $0.0676$ & $256.8037$ \\ 
   $0.1051$ & $273.6300$ \\
   $0.1556$ & $294.0302$ \\
   $0.1919$ & $307.4861$ \\ 
   $0.1953$ & $308.7253$ \\ 
   $0.1968$ & $309.2591$ \\
   $0.2534$ & $328.6548$ \\
   $0.2990$ & $343.2435$ \\ 
   $0.3179$ & $349.0466$ \\
   $0.3895$ & $369.9289$ \\
   $0.4080$ & $375.0633$ \\  
   $0.4723$ & $392.1812$ \\ 
   $0.5182$ & $403.7715$ \\  
   $0.5229$ & $404.9304$ \\
   $0.5929$ & $421.6356$ \\
   $0.6035$ & $424.0598$ \\
   $0.6379$ & $431.8383$ \\
   $0.6752$ & $439.9954$ \\
   $0.6874$ & $442.5920$ \\ 
   $0.7184$ & $449.1324$ \\ 
   $0.8319$ & $471.6474$ \\ 
   $0.9050$ & $485.0971$ \\  
   \end{tabular}
}\qquad
\subfloat[]{
\label{T2b}  
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
     $\beta_1(\tau)$ & $H(n_0, r_0)$ \\
\hline
   $0.0234$ & $19.5570$ \\ 
   $0.0287$ & $23.3547$ \\
   $0.0916$ & $61.9414$ \\ 
   $0.1618$ & $98.4688$ \\
   $0.1916$ & $112.7342$ \\ 
   $0.2434$ & $136.2445$ \\
   $0.2967$ & $159.0552$ \\
   $0.3323$ & $173.5709$ \\
   $0.3663$ & $187.0306$ \\
   $0.3979$ & $199.1778$ \\  
   $0.4143$ & $205.3392$ \\   
   $0.4356$ & $213.2420$ \\ 
   $0.5322$ & $247.4564$ \\
   $0.5467$ & $252.3924$ \\  
   $0.5784$ & $263.0127$ \\
   $0.7063$ & $303.6231$ \\
   $0.7185$ & $307.3005$ \\
   $0.7307$ & $310.9747$ \\ 
   $0.7392$ & $313.5350$ \\
   $0.7444$ & $315.0890$ \\ 
   $0.8524$ & $346.2092$ \\ 
   $0.8639$ & $349.4112$ \\ 
   $0.9382$ & $369.5946$ \\  
   $0.9954$ & $384.5563$ \\
   \end{tabular}
}\qquad
\subfloat[]{
\label{T2c}  
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
     $\beta_2(n_E)$ & $H(n_0, r_0)$ \\
\hline
   $0.0401$ & $41.6852$ \\         
   $0.0415$ & $42.8924$ \\ 
   $0.1459$ & $119.8971$ \\
   $0.1469$ & $120.4960$ \\
   $0.1697$ & $135.0943$ \\
   $0.1747$ & $138.1723$ \\
   $0.1808$ & $141.9400$ \\ 
   $0.2020$ & $154.8078$ \\
   $0.2415$ & $177.6726$ \\ 
   $0.2977$ & $208.3297$ \\  
   $0.4658$ & $289.4966$ \\
   $0.4678$ & $290.4147$ \\
   $0.4874$ & $299.0131$ \\
   $0.5592$ & $329.3742$ \\
   $0.5769$ & $336.5756$ \\
   $0.6298$ & $357.4931$ \\ 
   $0.6432$ & $362.6616$ \\
   $0.6440$ & $362.9452$ \\ 
   $0.6764$ & $375.1864$ \\
   $0.8121$ & $423.1673$ \\ 
   $0.9103$ & $454.9058$ \\ 
   $0.9216$ & $458.4156$ \\ 
   $0.9932$ & $479.9329$ \\  
   $0.9941$ & $480.2066$ \\  
    \end{tabular}
}\qquad
\subfloat[]{
\label{T2d}  
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
     $\gamma(R_E)$ & $H(n_0, r_0)$ \\
\hline
   $0.0130$ & $139.1077$ \\ 
   $0.0257$ & $146.9657$ \\
   $0.0611$ & $165.8004$ \\
   $0.0742$ & $172.1161$ \\
   $0.0779$ & $173.8204$ \\ 
   $0.0905$ & $179.5609$ \\ 
   $0.1394$ & $200.2853$ \\
   $0.1739$ & $213.6810$ \\
   $0.1862$ & $218.3039$ \\ 
   $0.2335$ & $235.1517$ \\
   $0.2408$ & $237.6320$ \\
   $0.2919$ & $254.5007$ \\
   $0.3034$ & $258.1202$ \\  
   $0.3256$ & $265.0310$ \\  
   $0.4231$ & $293.4047$ \\ 
   $0.4774$ & $308.0440$ \\  
   $0.4795$ & $308.5853$ \\    
   $0.4918$ & $311.7980$ \\
   $0.5051$ & $315.2074$ \\  
   $0.6566$ & $351.5110$ \\
   $0.6710$ & $354.7289$ \\
   $0.8568$ & $393.0985$ \\ 
   $0.8683$ & $395.2959$ \\ 
   $0.8702$ & $395.6473$ \\  
   \end{tabular}
}\qquad
\subfloat[]{
\label{T2e}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
     $t$ & $H(n_0, r_0)$ \\
\hline
   $1$ & $316.3187$ \\
   $2$ & $319.2520$ \\
   $3$ & $322.1979$ \\ 
   $4$ & $325.1567$ \\ 
   $5$ & $328.1296$ \\ 
   $6$ & $331.1179$ \\
   $7$ & $334.1225$ \\ 
   $8$ & $337.1443$ \\ 
   $9$ & $340.1836$ \\  
   $10$ & $343.2408$ \\ 
   $11$ & $346.3159$ \\ 
   $12$ & $349.4090$ \\ 
   $13$ & $352.5202$ \\ 
   $14$ & $355.6493$ \\ 
   $15$ & $358.7962$ \\ 
   $16$ & $361.9608$ \\  
   $17$ & $365.1430$ \\ 
   $18$ & $425.1145$ \\ 
   $19$ & $489.1914$ \\ 
   $19.5$ & $522.1258$ \\
   $19.75$ & $538.6532$ \\
   $19.99$ & $554.4819$ \\
   $20$ & $145.7364$ \\  
   $21$ & $145.7336$ \\
   \end{tabular}
}} 
\caption{The function}
\label{T2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE and Merry Christmas to you.

Comment: Please, remove the call to `newlfont`: it's a package meant for *very* old documents (pre-1992), not to be used in new ones. I'd also avoid `\usepackage{plain}`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `\subfloat` in a `table` environment expects the caption to be at the top.

I believe you are best served with the `subcaption` package instead of `subfig`, which doesn't suffer from the problem.

I also edited your tables to use `siunitx` features; I removed the vertical rule, you can reinstate it if you really want.

I also removed the unnecessary packages for the example. Note that `newlfont` is not to be used in new documents: it is a compatibility package for pre-1992 documents. Also I'd avoid `\usepackage{plain}`.

With `amsart` there's a neater way for changing the page parameters, with `\calclayout` as shown.

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\textwidth}{15cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{21cm}
\calclayout

\begin{document}

\ref{T2}, \ref{T2a}, \ref{T2b}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\subcaptionbox{\label{T2a}}{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}S[table-format=1.4]S[table-format=3.4]@{}}
    {$\alpha(E)$} & {$H(n_0, r_0)$} \\
    \hline
    0.0046 & 221.4469 \\ 
    0.0242 & 234.2140 \\
    0.0676 & 256.8037 \\ 
    0.1051 & 273.6300 \\
    0.1556 & 294.0302 \\
    0.1919 & 307.4861 \\ 
    0.1953 & 308.7253 \\ 
    0.1968 & 309.2591 \\
    0.2534 & 328.6548 \\
    0.2990 & 343.2435 \\ 
    0.3179 & 349.0466 \\
    0.3895 & 369.9289 \\
    0.4080 & 375.0633 \\  
    0.4723 & 392.1812 \\ 
    0.5182 & 403.7715 \\  
    0.5229 & 404.9304 \\
    0.5929 & 421.6356 \\
    0.6035 & 424.0598 \\
    0.6379 & 431.8383 \\
    0.6752 & 439.9954 \\
    0.6874 & 442.5920 \\ 
    0.7184 & 449.1324 \\ 
    0.8319 & 471.6474 \\ 
    0.9050 & 485.0971 \\  
  \end{tabular}%
}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{\label{T2b}}{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}S[table-format=1.4]S[table-format=3.4]@{}}
    {$\beta_1(\tau)$} & {$H(n_0, r_0)$} \\
    \hline
    0.0234 & 19.5570 \\ 
    0.0287 & 23.3547 \\
    0.0916 & 61.9414 \\ 
    0.1618 & 98.4688 \\
    0.1916 & 112.7342 \\ 
    0.2434 & 136.2445 \\
    0.2967 & 159.0552 \\
    0.3323 & 173.5709 \\
    0.3663 & 187.0306 \\
    0.3979 & 199.1778 \\  
    0.4143 & 205.3392 \\   
    0.4356 & 213.2420 \\ 
    0.5322 & 247.4564 \\
    0.5467 & 252.3924 \\  
    0.5784 & 263.0127 \\
    0.7063 & 303.6231 \\
    0.7185 & 307.3005 \\
    0.7307 & 310.9747 \\ 
    0.7392 & 313.5350 \\
    0.7444 & 315.0890 \\ 
    0.8524 & 346.2092 \\ 
    0.8639 & 349.4112 \\ 
    0.9382 & 369.5946 \\  
    0.9954 & 384.5563 \\
  \end{tabular}%
}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{\label{T2c}}{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}S[table-format=1.4]S[table-format=3.4]@{}}
    {$\beta_2(n_E)$} & {$H(n_0, r_0)$} \\
    \hline
    0.0401 & 41.6852 \\         
    0.0415 & 42.8924 \\ 
    0.1459 & 119.8971 \\
    0.1469 & 120.4960 \\
    0.1697 & 135.0943 \\
    0.1747 & 138.1723 \\
    0.1808 & 141.9400 \\ 
    0.2020 & 154.8078 \\
    0.2415 & 177.6726 \\ 
    0.2977 & 208.3297 \\  
    0.4658 & 289.4966 \\
    0.4678 & 290.4147 \\
    0.4874 & 299.0131 \\
    0.5592 & 329.3742 \\
    0.5769 & 336.5756 \\
    0.6298 & 357.4931 \\ 
    0.6432 & 362.6616 \\
    0.6440 & 362.9452 \\ 
    0.6764 & 375.1864 \\
    0.8121 & 423.1673 \\ 
    0.9103 & 454.9058 \\ 
    0.9216 & 458.4156 \\ 
    0.9932 & 479.9329 \\  
    0.9941 & 480.2066 \\  
  \end{tabular}%
}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{\label{T2d}}{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}S[table-format=1.4]S[table-format=3.4]@{}}
    {$\gamma(R_E)$} & {$H(n_0, r_0)$} \\
    \hline
    0.0130 & 139.1077 \\ 
    0.0257 & 146.9657 \\
    0.0611 & 165.8004 \\
    0.0742 & 172.1161 \\
    0.0779 & 173.8204 \\ 
    0.0905 & 179.5609 \\ 
    0.1394 & 200.2853 \\
    0.1739 & 213.6810 \\
    0.1862 & 218.3039 \\ 
    0.2335 & 235.1517 \\
    0.2408 & 237.6320 \\
    0.2919 & 254.5007 \\
    0.3034 & 258.1202 \\  
    0.3256 & 265.0310 \\  
    0.4231 & 293.4047 \\ 
    0.4774 & 308.0440 \\  
    0.4795 & 308.5853 \\    
    0.4918 & 311.7980 \\
    0.5051 & 315.2074 \\  
    0.6566 & 351.5110 \\
    0.6710 & 354.7289 \\
    0.8568 & 393.0985 \\ 
    0.8683 & 395.2959 \\ 
    0.8702 & 395.6473 \\  
  \end{tabular}%
}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{\label{T2e}}{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}S[table-format=2.2]S[table-format=3.4]@{}}
    {$t$} & {$H(n_0, r_0)$} \\
    \hline
    1 & 316.3187 \\
    2 & 319.2520 \\
    3 & 322.1979 \\ 
    4 & 325.1567 \\ 
    5 & 328.1296 \\ 
    6 & 331.1179 \\
    7 & 334.1225 \\ 
    8 & 337.1443 \\ 
    9 & 340.1836 \\  
    10 & 343.2408 \\ 
    11 & 346.3159 \\ 
    12 & 349.4090 \\ 
    13 & 352.5202 \\ 
    14 & 355.6493 \\ 
    15 & 358.7962 \\ 
    16 & 361.9608 \\  
    17 & 365.1430 \\ 
    18 & 425.1145 \\ 
    19 & 489.1914 \\ 
    19.5 & 522.1258 \\
    19.75 & 538.6532 \\
    19.99 & 554.4819 \\
    20 & 145.7364 \\  
    21 & 145.7336 \\
  \end{tabular}%
}
\caption{The function}
\label{T2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions come to mind:

1. make use of the `\subref` command provided by the [`subfig` package](ftp://ftp.mpi-sb.mpg.de/pub/tex/mirror/ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/subfig.pdf) which you use for making the `\subfloat`s. i.e. try `Table \ref{T2} \subref{T2a}` and `Tables \ref{T2} \subref{T2b}, \subref{T2c}, \subref{T2d} and \subref{T2e}` and you get "Table 1(a)" and "Tables 1 (b), (c), (d) and (e)" respectively. Of course this can be tweaked if you want the table number repeated in front of the letters: `Tables \ref{T2} (\ref{T2}\subref{T2b}), ...` gives "Tables 1 (1b), ...".
2. move the `\caption` command before all the `\label` commands for the `\subfloat`s and you get: "Table 1 (1a)" and "Tables 1 (1b), (1c), (1d) and (1e)" from `Table \ref{T2} \eqref{T2a}` and `Tables \ref{T2} \eqref{T2b}, \eqref{T2c}, \eqref{T2d} and \eqref{T2e}`

Comment: Thank you, however, a minor problem exists yet: The subtables labels are as capital letters i.e. (A), (B), (C), (D) and (D), but applying \subref  we get (a), (b), (c), (d) and (e).

Comment: this is easily fixed by adding `\renewcommand{\thesubtable}{\Alph{subtable}}` in the preample

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to put the table inside another table.  You have three tables in a table.  I've done this in mathjax.

Comment: I do not get your point. Please explain what you mean by this idea.

Comment: You make a table with one row, and three cells, and you insert a table into a cell of the first, so eg  \begin{tabular}{ccc}  \\ \begin{tabular} Table 1 \end{tabular} & {begin{tabular} Table2 \end{tabular & begin{tabular} Table3 \end{tabular \\ \endtabular